# sort by childs count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I want to order by Posts comments count. But this code is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

model Post

```
has_many :comments
scope :active, where("active = ?", true)  
scope :popular, active.limit(10).sort { |a, b| b.comments.size <=> a.comments.size }
```

model Comment

```
belongs_to :post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_many :comments
scope :active, where("active = ?", true)
scope :popular, active.joins(:comments).select("posts.*, count(posts.id) as a_c").group("comments.post_id").order("a_c DESC").limit(10)
```

Comment: what? I don't actually understand what you need

Comment: it is listing posts by their comments size but if a post has 0 comments it is not in the list

Comment: you should use `counter_cache` here